# Why I can't access a vuejs instance variable from a closure?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to learn vue 2, but I'm stuck, could someone help me on why I can't access this component within an event closure? 
No errors in the console thought it doesn't get rendered

Probably unuseful information: 
Babel, webpack, vue-loader, event bus works though not the first time, I supose that the component is not created still but I think that is not the real problem

```
<template>
    <div class="w3-row-padding">
        <div class="w3-pannel">{{categoryName}}</div>
        <categoria-admin v-for="number in 9"></categoria-admin> 
    </div>
</template>




<script>

    import Bus from '../Classes/Bus';

    export default {

        data: function () {
            return {
                //Bind vari to template doesn't work either
                vari: "varivari"
            };
        },
        //tried with oncreate too
        mounted: function () {
            this.vari = "foo";//it works
            // I tried with es5 passing this through a variable, doesn't work either
              Bus.$on('categoria-item-selected', ( category ) => {
                    console.log("entering closure");// this get printed
                    this.vari = "ha funcionado" // doesn't work
                    this.updateVari('ha funcionado');// doesnt work
                    console.log(this.vari); // prints ha funcionado , but in template 
                                            //is not reflected and with chrome tool either
              });
        },
        computed: {
            categoryName : function () {
                return this.vari;
            }
        },
        methods: {
            updateVari: function ( value ){
                this.vari = value;
            }
        }


    }
</script>
```

Comment: What is Bus? Is it a Vue object? If you `console.log(this)` in the event handler, what does it log?

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce it. Your code seems to work fine:

(click a button to emit your event, then variable value will change - notice text above the button)

```js
const bus = new Vue({});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    foldersList: [{id: 1, name: 'first'}, {id: 2, name: 'second'}],
    foldersStatus: true
  },
  methods: {
   emitMe: function() {
     bus.$emit('myevent');
   }
  },
  components: {
    'child' : {
      template: `<p>{{ vari }}</p>`,
      data: function() {
       return {
          vari: 'varivari'
        }
      },
      mounted() {
       this.vari = "foo";
        bus.$on('myevent', (category) => {
          console.log("entering closure");// this get printed
          this.vari = "ha funcionado";
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <child></child>
  <button @click="emitMe()">Emit</button>
</div>
```

Often, when you experience such issues, you should save current `this` to a variable like this: `const self = this` and refer to `self` in async callbacks etc. But in this case it seems to work ok and `this` remains the same.

Comment: "Often, when you experience such issues, you should save current this to a variable like this: const self = this and refer to self in async callbacks etc"